# HOW TO CHANGE/REPLACE THE COM PORT FOR A USB SERIAL ADAPTER ON ARCH LINUX

Tags: serial-port, archlinux

I would want to know the **commands or the procedure to change/replace the comports number in archlinux**, as done in windows by going into device manager.

Basically I have a sensor connected to the system which sends ascii codes to the archlinux system. I want to replace this sensor by another one, which is serially connected to the archlinux system and simply change the comports of these two sensors, so that the system takes the same ascii code from the new sensor and performs accordingly.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue what you mean by *replace*, you cannot replace a port with a software command.  Serial ports are hardware components.  Yet, the mapping between MS Windows COM ports and Linux devices is simply:

```
MS windows | Linux
---------- | -----
COM1       | /dev/ttyS0
COM2       | /dev/ttyS1
COM3       | /dev/ttyS2
```

`/dev/ttyS*` are simply character devices, you can read/write to them almost like a file:

```
# echo yay > /dev/ttyS0
# cat /dev/ttyS0
```

Also, `man setserial` is very informative on the parameters for serial ports.

Comment: I have two devices and  found their ports by $ lsusb , $ dmesg. Also their id by $ udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSBx The sensor which sends the ascii code to the archlinux system is at ttyUSB1 and the system reads these ascii codes from ttyUSB1. I have connected a new senor to send the same ascii codes which is at ttyUSB0. I want to set this new sensor to the port ttyUSB1, so that instead of reading from the old sensor, i could use this new sensor to feed  ascii codes to the archlinux system.